# My onepage checkout for CC doesn't work in Magento 1.3.3, also can't save products

Tags: magento

I have just developed a couple of problems in my magento install that I have had running for the past year and not sure if I've created them or not.

Paypal payments on my site are processed just fine, but on the onepage checkout for credit cards, when the customer enters their address information and presses "continue", the button doesn't do anything.  It comes up with a little "loading" button, then it just goes away and you are sitting there on the same page.

I cannot save my changes to products, or new products that I am trying to add.  This is a big problem I need immediate help with!!  It just hangs when I press "Save"

I also cannot expand my category trees in the Manage Categories section.  When I click on the + sign, it just disappears and doesn't expand the folders.

Please can someone help me?  I'm new to this and don't have a clue!!!

Answer (score 2):

For credit card issue : just add this line in `/app/design/frontend/default/YOURTHEME/layout/page.xml` for js

```
<action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
```

in this block

```
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering please use the formatting buttons on the editor's toolbar so your HTML can be seen.